# Google shows image alt text in the search result rather than the meta description

Tags: seo, google-search, meta-description, search-results

Google search shows random alt text of images in my site instead of the meta description tag text. I couldn't find similar problems on the net so I guess I'm doing something wrong, but what is it?

If I delete the alt text, it shows some random text from the footer.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without knowing what your meta description contains, how descriptive of the content it is, and how much it matches the search query. See:  [Why Google Rewrites Meta Descriptions](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/why-google-rewrites-meta-descriptions/370452/). You can try to make sure you're using a keyword in it that you're searching for, and it accurately matches both the page's content and the search query you're using.

Comment: See also: [Google is not picking up meta description approximately 50 percent of the time on our website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67605/google-is-not-picking-up-meta-description-approximately-50-percent-of-the-time-o)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my experience, google shows well some low-volume keywords and related keywords with your main keyword in alt text of images.
If you delete alt text, you can see some low-competitive keywords and related keywords.
If you have no other related keywords in your page, maybe shown text will be related with backlink texts.
The possibility of upper case is about 30 ~ 40% in my experience.
This is just my experience. The result may be different from other cases.